# (Python) Help fixing a Hangman Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I really need help to fix this code. Basically, it is a hangman game whereby users can guess *letters* or *words*.

If the user enters a letter, it will work like a regular hangman game. However, the final chance (Guess #6) must be a word. If the user used letter guesses and got it correct before Guess #6, user would not go through the word guess.

The user can guess the word beforehand but if it is wrong, they will lose 2 chances. So if they guess the wrong word in the beginning, they will have 4 chances left but the last chance will still be the word guess.

edit: The program will now only have 5 letter guesses whether right or wrong but the final guess will still be a word guess and we still have the optional early word guesses. The counter appears to be working now but I am unsure how to separate the words. (edit: I have realised that there is also a problem to append the words.)

This is my current code.
I changed the part when its (counter < 5) in user guess.
The part where (counter == 5) is like the old code to compare.

```
import random

wordlist = 'artist breeze circle decent enroll filthy growth honest invest kernel letter narrow meteor policy pursue roster runway scheme ripple toddle wobbly zeroes'.upper().split()
random.shuffle(wordlist)
counter = 0

def draw_board():
    #Display words here
    for i in secret_word:
        if i in correct:
            print(i, end=' ')
        else:
            print('_', end=' ')
    print("\n")
    print("*** MISSES ***")
    for i in incorrect:
        print(i, end=' ')
    print('\n*********************')


def user_guess():
    #For user to input guess
    global counter
    secret_word = wordlist.pop()
    while(counter < 5):        
        guess = input("Guess a letter or word\n: ").upper()
        if(len(guess) > 1):
            guess_list = list(guess)
            if(guess_list == secret_list):
                correct.append(guess_list)
            else:
                counter = counter + 1
        elif guess in secret_word:
            correct.append(guess)
        else:
            incorrect.append(guess)
        return counter
    if(counter == 5):
        wordguess = input("Enter your word\n: ").upper()
        if(guess == secret_word):
            correct.append(wordguess)
        else:
            counter = counter + 1
            print(counter)
    return counter

def check_win():
    #Check if user has won or not
    global counter
    if(counter > 5):
        return 'loss'
    for i in secret_word:
        if i not in correct:
            return 'no win'
    return 'win'

#pop is used to retrieve a word from word list
secret_word = wordlist.pop()
secret_list = list(secret_word)
correct = []
incorrect = []
print("DEBUG: %s" % secret_word)

while True:
    draw_board()
    user_guess()
    counter = counter + 1
    win_condition = check_win()
    if win_condition == 'loss':
        print("You lose!")
        break
    elif win_condition == 'win':
        print("You win!")
```

Comment: What is the specific problem with the code? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: @Peter The program does not detect when user enters a word so even if user enters the correct word, it will go on with the game. It also goes on continuously despite the chances exceeding 6 so there must be a flaw in the counter or logic somewhere. Sorry for not addressing the question properly. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 things that should be changed here to avoid extra loops.

1. Add a break after `print("you win")`
2. Delete `counter = 0` in user_guess and replace `def user_guess():` with 
   `def user_guess(counter):`
3. Replace `user_guess()` with `counter = user_guess(counter)`

Additionally you should probably change the whiles in user_guess() to ifs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways of debugging your issue. The first is to scatter print statements around to show what's happening, the second is using a debugger like [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html).

The debugger allows you to step through your code and is the best way to track down problems, so you should learn how to use it, however print statements are often useful and are easy to understand, so I'll demonstrate that here.

It sounds like the game is drawing correctly, so we'll focus on the logic. Let's put in print statements to show the program state while in the main `while` loop. (I've also removed some unnecessary print statements to shorten the output).

```
while True:
    draw_board()
    user_guess()
    win_condition = check_win(counter)
    print('secret_word: {}, correct: {}, incorrect: {}, counter: {}, win_condition: {}'.format(
        secret_word, correct, incorrect, counter, win_condition))

    if win_condition == 'loss':
        print("You lose!")
        break
    elif win_condition == 'win':
        print("You win!")
```

Here's a sample game with this output:

```
Guess a letter or word: a
secret_word: ZEROES, correct: [], incorrect: ['A'], counter: 0, win_condition: no win
_ _ _ _ _ _ *** MISSES ***
A
Guess a letter or word: e
secret_word: ZEROES, correct: ['E'], incorrect: ['A'], counter: 0, win_condition: no win
_ E _ _ E _ *** MISSES ***
A
Guess a letter or word: n
secret_word: ZEROES, correct: ['E'], incorrect: ['A', 'N'], counter: 0, win_condition: no win
_ E _ _ E _ *** MISSES ***
A N
Guess a letter or word: t
secret_word: ZEROES, correct: ['E'], incorrect: ['A', 'N', 'T'], counter: 0, win_condition: no win
_ E _ _ E _ *** MISSES ***
A N T
Guess a letter or word: zeroes
secret_word: ZEROES, correct: ['E', 'ZEROES'], incorrect: ['A', 'N', 'T'], counter: 0, win_condition: no win
_ E _ _ E _ *** MISSES ***
A N T
Guess a letter or word: test
secret_word: ZEROES, correct: ['E', 'ZEROES'], incorrect: ['A', 'N', 'T'], counter: 0, win_condition: no win
_ E _ _ E _ *** MISSES ***
A N T
```

So straight away we can see some problems.

- `counter` is not being incremented after each guess
- when I guessed the correct word, it appends the whole word to the `correct` list instead of the individual letters
- when I guessed an incorrect word, `counter` is not changing

So, some issues to fix:

- make sure you're capturing the return value of `user_guess` (counter) and assigning it to your global `counter` variable - these two are separate variables due to scope. You could also just put `global counter` in your `user_guess` function
- make sure you increment counter after each incorrect guess
- don't reset counter to zero at each user guess
- `correct.append(guess)` should be changed to append each letter individually

Try making those changes and testing again. Add some more print statements if you're still having issues and see if you can find the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I'm sorry to bother again but despite the issues being addressed, I'm not sure how to fix those problems nor find solutions for them. How do I go about this?

Comment: @Sar What did you try? Can you update the question with the issues you ran into after the changes?

Comment: I have updated the question. So far, I only managed to get global counter to work.